# pam-auth-update does not display prompt screen or log any failure

Tags: ubuntu, pam

```
~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise

~# dpkg -l \*pam\* | grep ii
ii  libpam-krb5                          4.5-3                               PAM module for MIT Kerberos
ii  libpam-modules                       1.1.3-7ubuntu2                      Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM
ii  libpam-modules-bin                   1.1.3-7ubuntu2                      Pluggable Authentication Modules for PAM - helper binaries
ii  libpam-runtime                       1.1.3-7ubuntu2                      Runtime support for the PAM library
ii  libpam0g                             1.1.3-7ubuntu2                      Pluggable Authentication Modules library
```

trying to run pam-auth-update on this particular box.  Other boxes causea  prompt screen to pop up.  This particular box, however, does absolutely nothing with no feedback or logs as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

`pam-auth-update` is a perl script, try `perl -d /usr/sbin/pam-auth-update`

Perhaps you will get something.